# Photoshop CC Color Replacement Substitution issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

When I use the 'Replace Color...' to  change `#F5F5F5` to `#EDE8D5`, Photoshop is automatically changing my desired value to `#E2E2E2` after I click OK. Any ideas as to why? The color mode is set to 8-bit RGB.

Edited to add that I did use threshhold to and a filter to create a stencil type of image, but shouldn't I be able to add color back in after those adjustment have been made?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a layer somewhere inside your file that changes the colors of whatever is underneath it, like hue saturation or levels or something like that. 
Here's how you check:
On the layers window choose kind and then choose adjustment layer and you will be left only with adjustment layers, run them on and off untill you fint the one that's causing all the trouble:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok the Photoshop 'Replace Color' function does not seem to actually replace colors to the exact value. You can try another approach:

Go to **Select** > **Color Range** > Choose the color you want to change with **color picker** > Adjust **fuzziness** accordingly (I'd recommend 100) > Press **OK** and **fill the selection** with your desired new color, preferably in a new layer.